# Can anyone make a text(""); function?

Tags: javascript

I need help making a function that works like `document.write("");` I need it to be called by using `text("");` instead of printing out `document.write("");` every single time. I just want to be able to use something other than `document.write("");` every time. Here is what I have:

```
<script>
function text(a) {document.write("");}
text("Hi.");
</script>
```

But the function needs a parameter in the function to work. Can anyone help?
P.S. The real question is: "Can anyone help with making a `text("");` function?"

Comment: Actually *use* the parameter you're passing in, and declaring in the method?

Comment: you need to use the parameter you have passed

Comment: Unrelated, but are you sure you really want to be writing to the document so much that you need to encapsulate it in a utility function?

Comment: Ask for clarifications before downvoting so hard...

Comment: How about just using `appendChild`, `insertBefore` and the other javascript methods that are actually usable for something ?

Comment: @procrastinator There's no need for clarifications; the question and error are crystal-clear.

Comment: Also, upvoting in sympathy is inappropriate. While there's no need to continue downvoting, it's not a *good* question, either.

Comment: @DaveNewton So, why downvoting? Just answer.

Comment: @procrastinator Because it's a bad question? Unlikely to help others? Not searchable in a meaningful way? Easy to figure out with only a modicum of JS tutorial?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think so.

Comment: Hey! I have just started learning how to use JavaScript. I'm 13. Not a pro.

Comment: @procrastinator Then SO may not be a great fit for you. As flexible as I am, I am unable to come up with a reasonable rebuttal for the reasons I listed.

Comment: @KingKreeper17 Then I'd suggest going through some JS tutorials, because most (all?) describe functions and how to write/use them, and their arguments. It's almost always better to slog through this kind of thing on your own for a significant amount of time *before* asking for help. It's more satisfying, and more educational. YMMV.

Comment: @KingKreeper17 Also note that asking a bad question on SO is just, and only, that. We don't vote on people, we vote on questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221781/are-sympathy-enthusiasm-upvotes-legitimate. (At least in general, there are some users that break that convention.)

Comment: Ok. I will do that. (That was going to be my next focus, but I guess I'll start now.) Thanks. :)

Comment: @KingKreeper17 Consider something like [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html). It has both explanations and a way to execute things "built-in", and if you can get through it, you're well on your way.

Comment: @DaveNewton I understand now. The problem with this system is that, sometimes, "bad" questions like this one still deserve an answer, but the more there are downvotes, the less you are likely to get it. Anyway, I guess this problem has already been debated before on Meta.

Comment: @procrastinator And the question may be deleted, sometimes before the OP has a chance to read it. [I've argued this fairly strongly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228085/i-dont-believe-this-question-should-have-been-closed-or-deleted), to the point of me mostly leaving SO.

Comment: This may be frustrating indeed.

Comment: Thanks for getting me "question banned". All I wanted was an answer.

Comment: It's not like I'm trying to spam stackoverflow. It's more like I'm not very good at wording things.

Comment: I guess I'll go to ask.com and get either a bad answer or no answer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
<script>
function text(a) {document.write(a);}
text("Hi.");
</script>
```

Comment: I guess some people just don't like to make things easier.

Comment: @KingKreeper17 Developers are the *kings* of making things easier, and we'll [shave yaks](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving) to a ridiculous extent to do so. Here the issues are that it's a poor question for SO, *and* encouraging a suspect practice of directly writing to the page, which is occasionally, but rarely, necessary.

Comment: I just wanted to have something simple to make something else more simple. I mean, the best program I have ever made is a calculator that can only take 2 numbers.